# How do I create a jquery loader that interfaces with Ruby/Sinatra?

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I have a simple website scraper that I'm practicing on building in Ruby + Sinatra + Nokogiri.

I have a loader called  that semi-transparently covers up the entire screen.

As of right now, its set to the following for when the page initially loads (usually theres a large amount of data on the page at any given time when its loaded initially)

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#loading').fadeOut();
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn();
});
```

My question is, is it possible to activate this loader and then 'unactivate' it during my ruby script while nokogiri is working?

For example, in...

```
post '/refresh' do
  # scraping code here that can take seconds to minutes
end
```

I want to enable the loader at the beginning, then disable it at the end. Not sure how I would go about doing this, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but I think in general you want to run the scraper from an ajax call and disable the loader in the onComplete callback

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into Sinatra's before and after filters

Comment: Do you have perhaps an idea of what I might put in there? or functions i should look up that I would be using. Im kind of new to this.